# Get value at some memory address in Fortran

Tags: pointers, memory, fortran

I have a boolean variable BVAR, in a subroutine SUBA that changes when I call a subroutine SUBB, from SUBA. BVAR is not passed as argument to SUBB, there is probably some problem happening with the array declarations, and I don't know how to find it.

I know that I can get BVAR memory address with LOC(BVAR), and I want to know when in SUBB the value at this address is changed. As there are many variables and many other subroutines called in SUBB, it's not practical to ask for the memory address of all variables in SUBB.

Thank you

Comment: I'm using Intel 2011 with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Since you seem to be asking for debugging purposes, have you tried making a debug build, setting breakpoints and inspecting what is happening? A debugger lets you interrogate many variables across many subroutines.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I should point out that this is probably *NOT* the right way to solve your original problem with your program. Rather, you should **enable all compiler checks and use a debugger**. See many similar questions on this site.

But to answer your question: You can try to read from any address you want with some tricks. If the address is invalid and the program crashes or becomes behaving in a strange way, it is your responsibility.

```
use iso_c_binding

type(c_ptr) :: p
integer(c_intptr_t) :: i8

real, pointer :: fp !(or any other type)

!!if you have BVAR available
!p = c_loc(BVAR)
!or
!p = transfer(loc(BVAR), p)

!from any numeric address
i8 = 1564234_c_intptr_t   

p = transfer(i8, p)

call c_f_pointer(p, fp)

print *,fp
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers

Compiler diagnostics is probably a good idea, but since there is some part of the code  that uses very old conventions, I've already had some problems with them.

Actually I solved the problem by running part of the internal subroutine and skipping the rest (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), to see what was making the change in the external variable.
I found the line and found that there was a varible, passed as argument, that was declared differently in the 2 subroutines, and then using the memory of the other variable.